# How to pass variable to php script from Jquery $(document).ready function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, scroll

I am building a chat. I have this Jquery working code which calls logs.php every second and refreshes the chat.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');
            updateScroll();
        }, 1000);      
    }
);
```

As you can see, also `updateScroll`, a JS function on my page, gets called. `Updatescroll` creates a variable, which I would like to pass on to `logs.php`, is there any way to do this? In other words, `updatescroll` basically checks everysecond if the user has scrolled up to the top of the chat. If so, I am gonna tell `logs.php` to load -say - another 10 messages. But in order to do this, I have to have something that from `updatescroll` passes on to the Jquery function and thus onto `logs.php`. You get it? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to implement an "infinite scroll" feature? There are lots of plugins that do this.

Answer (score 1):

First, when it comes to ajax, I would recommend using a `window.setTimeout`, intervals can get tricky when you are running things asynchronously (if one call hangs you can end up with multiple calls to the same script).

so something more like:

```
(function($){
    var update_messages = function(){
        var count = updateScroll();
        $('#chatlogs').load('logs.php?count='+count, function(){
            window.setTimeout(update_messages, 1000);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        update_messages();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then in your PHP script the "count" would be available via `$_GET['count']`.

EDIT: you can see an anonymous function is being sent as a second argument to load, this will be called AFTER the AJAX call is complete, so we can make sure only 1 of these is running at a time

Comment: Hi, the +count works, but one IMPORTANT thing: I don't want (can't) define the count variable in the Jquery code. I wanna define it in the JS updatescroll function I call. I've tried defining it there, but it won't pass its value onto 'logs.php?count='+count, see what I mean?

Comment: That's fine, in the example I just assumed you could return the count from the updateScroll function.

Comment: Maybe you should post the updateScroll function here too